# Why does setTimeout not trigger after specified time

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am running a very basic javascript code in Viusal Studio Code.  However I am not seeing the callback function get triggered.

I am trying to understand how setTimeout() works in javascript.  I am running the following code (in file called test.js) in Visual Studio code as follows:

> > node test.js

```
'use strict'

let timerexpired = false;
setTimeout( function() {console.log(`setting timerexpired to true...`);
                        timerexpired = true;
                        }, 
                        5000);

while(1) {
    console.log(`timerexpired = `, timerexpired);

    if (timerexpired) {
        console.log(`timer expired.  Resume execution`);
        break;
    } else {
        console.log(`keep on spinning`);
    }

}
```

Expect the loop to break after 5000 ms.  But it keeps on spinning with output as "keep on spinning"

Comment: Your loop is blocking the execution of anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call `setTimeout` or when you do any blocking operation for that matter, it's in fact added to an event table and not executed immediately.

It's only after the call stack is empty that the event loop check the event table to see if there's anything waiting, and move it to the call stack.

To better understand this, check the following example:

```
setTimeout(() => console.log('first'), 0)
console.log('second')
```

You may think that `first` will be logged before `second`, but in fact it's `second` that will be logged first.

In your example the call stack is never empty, so `setTimeout` won't really work as expected.

You may wanna check [this](https://hackernoon.com/understanding-js-the-event-loop-959beae3ac40), it will give you a better idea about what's happening under the hood.

Comment: From Hamza's post below and your comment yes, it seems to be the case. I guess the real reason is that Javascript is event driven AND is single threaded. So if the thread is always busy (executing the while loop), it never gets a chance to check for the event timeout and therefore callback is never triggered?

Answer (score 1):

While(1) is an infinite while loop. I think that is the reason