# setTimeout failing on certain laptops

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am running a speaking test that plays the audio instructions, then plays a video question and finally starts recording and a countdown clock.  What I have found is that this works perfectly for some students but on some laptops there is no delay between the events, which of course messes up the test completely.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    var audio = new Audio('/audio/listening01.mp3');
    audio.play(); 
    setTimeout(function(){
        var vid = document.getElementById("myVideo1");
        vid.play();
        setTimeout(function(){
            clockSetUp();
            var audio = new Audio('/audio/beep.mp3');
            audio.play();
            var mic = document.getElementById("mic1");
            recordParts1("<?php echo ('1_' . $myID1) ?>");
            mic.src = "/images/micGreen.png";
            setTimeout(function(){
                var mic = document.getElementById("mic1");
                mic.src = "/images/mic.png";
                document.getElementById("myNext2").style.display = "block";
            },30000);
        },1000 + <?php echo ($video1length) ?>);
    },16000);   
},1000);
break;
```

I had originally coded this using a series of setTimeouts but then tried nesting to see if that would overcome the issue (the php is simply supplying the length of the videos in ms).  Sorry for the messy code, I will tidy it up once I get to the bottom of the issue.

I have Googled the issue to death but can't find any such behaviour being discussed and can't find anything in the machine or software specs that would account for this happening to some students but not others.

I do understand that setTimeout is not an accurate measure of time, but this question is not about delays in the timeout it is about the setTimeout being ignored on some laptops.

Comment: It's not clear specifically what you're asking.  The question title mentions `setInterval`, but the code doesn't use `setInterval`.  For the code shown, what specifically is failing?

Comment: *on some laptops there is no delay between the events*: `setTimeout` times are not guaranteed. Depending on what else is happening in that page they may or may not run exactly as you expect them to. If for example you block on the event table, the setTimeout could run much later

Comment: if the PHP code is safe and useless, just take it out and post the code you can see on your browser (you should also check the console, and possibly check that JS is activated on all the browsers )

Comment: may be check developer console to see if there is any error. Also try to find if there is any similarity between system setup where this is failing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does setTimeout not trigger after specified time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55856739/why-does-settimeout-not-trigger-after-specified-time)

Comment: You probably want to start your timers after the audio is complete.

Comment: Instead of relying on predefined timeouts I think you should use the audio/video events like "canplay", "ended" etc.: https://www.w3.org/2010/05/video/mediaevents.html

Comment: I know setTimeout times aren't accurate but this is a case of it working fine on some laptops but not others.  As if the setTimeout weren't being invoked.

Comment: I am the one creating the page, it is not failing for me, so I'm not sure what to expect from the console.  I'm not sure why removing the php improve the post.  If JS were not activated then none of the code would be running, so this isn't the issue.

Comment: Thanks Dinh, that is one option I looked at but I still need to be able to trigger other events after a fixed time, so would still need to use setTimeout for some events (this is just one part of my code).  But this would certainly avoid the issue of audio and video playing at the same time. So a partially correct answer.

Comment: My best guess of the original issue is that `<?php echo ($video1length) ?>` is evaluating to something that's not a number, so you end up passing `NaN` to one of the `setInterval`s, which probably gets treated as zero, causing events to trigger together. Check the source of the page to see what PHP is substituting there (or test without that PHP, just use a number). But the above suggestions to use `ended` events would definitely be better.

Comment: That's not a bad call but I don't think it wouldn't result in the behaviour I am seeing.  If the php were returning NaN, then I still believe the audio file would play first and then the video and recording would happen together, not all three together.  I will however test the theory. I'm not sure how this would only happen with certain students and not others.  The problem with testing this is that it is only occurring on a few students' computers and I am not in a position to test the issue on their machines.

Comment: As I said previously the ended events would certainly solve a couple of issues, so is a partial solution but there are still events that will require the use of setTimeout or similar (for example, in another part of the code there is a pause between the video prompt ending and the audio recording starting).

Comment: I have tested the page replacing the php with a hard coded "NaN" and it simply breaks the javaScript, so that the page can't load.  The php values are being correctly inserted into the code.